Is it possible to use this light socket for a projector? (EU)
I've moved into a home in Sweden and there's a light socket installed high on a wall, pictured here. The socket takes small plug designed especially for light fixtures, like this. I want to use this socket to power a projector, which uses a regular Europlug.
Is this possible (e.g. with an adapter), and would this be safe?

First, you should check local codes, both at the time the socket was installed, and currently, for the current that it was designed. A socket designed for a small lamp, drawing perhaps 1 ampere, might not be wired for the current the projector requires (which should be stated in the question).
Second, there is no ground connection. Perhaps the metal screw in the photo connects to ground, or not. Most projectors require a grounded outlet.
Personally, if at all unsure, it might be better to at least replace the socket with one that is grounded, if the wiring behind it has a ground conductor and if the wire is heavy enough for the projector's current. If not, then perhaps a new cable can be snaked through without cutting open the wall.

It looks like the europlug link, does not have/use ground.

can confirm, europlug is non-polarised and ungrounded and used for appliances up-to 2.5A.

Thanks, both for checking. As-is, I would not use it for powering a projector, but the wiring behind that outlet might, or might not, be usable.
